# Return type of one of the 'if' blocks is not compatible with return type of other block(s)

Tags: pine-script

Receiving the error below on v4

I am trying to blend to search for all crosses on the 9/20/200/vwap and set up a back test strategy for review.

*lines 39:45: Return type of one of the 'if' blocks is not compatible with return type of other block(s) (series[float]; void)*

```
strategy("DC and GC 9 20 200 EMA VWAP TESTING")

ema9 = ema(close, 9)
ema20 = ema(close, 20)
ema200 = ema(close, 200)
vwap = vwap(close)

long = ema200 > vwap
short = ema200 < vwap

longcondition = long and long[1] and not long [2]
shortcondition = short and short[1] and not short [2]

closelong = ema9 < ema20 and not long[2]
closeshort= ema9 < ema20 and not short[2]

plot(ema9, title="9", color =#1E90FF, linewidth=1) 
plot(ema20, title="20", color =#00FF00, linewidth=2)
plot(ema200, title="200", color =#FF9800, linewidth=3)
plot(vwap, title="vwap", color =#311B92, linewidth=3)


start = timestamp(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0)
end = timestamp(2022, 5, 19, 0, 0)

if time >= start and time <=end

    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 1000.0, when = longcondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, 1000.0, when = shortcondition)

//Trailing Stop
Trailperc=0.2
price_stop=0.0

if (strategy.position_size>0)
    stopvalue=close*(1-Trailperc)
    price_stop:=max(stopValue,price_stop[1])
else
    price_stop:=0
    if (strategy.position_size>0)
        strategy.exit(id="stoploss", stop=price_stop)
```

Answer (score 4):

If blocks should return the same type.

This block returns `float` (`price_stop`).

```
if (strategy.position_size>0)
    stopvalue=close*(1-Trailperc)
    price_stop:=max(stopValue,price_stop[1])
```

Therefore, below should also return a `float`.

```
else
    price_stop:=0
    if (strategy.position_size>0)
        strategy.exit(id="stoploss", stop=price_stop)
```

To fix that, you can just return a dummy `float` value.

```
if (strategy.position_size>0)
    stopvalue=close*(1-Trailperc)
    price_stop:=max(stopValue,price_stop[1])
else
    price_stop:=0
    if (strategy.position_size>0)
        strategy.exit(id="stoploss", stop=price_stop)
        0.0  // Dummy float return
```